# Rapidminer - k-means query

Tags: rapidminer

Sorry if this is a very novice question to ask But I have recently started exploring Rapidminer. I have used it to cluster my sample data [using K-means clustering]. My query is if I use a excel raw data file to cluster, how will I get my excel data back [output data] split into K clusters in excel file. I know how to create cluster and switch between the Design and Results screens.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to stackoverflow and RapidMiner.

If I understand your question correctly, you read your data from excel, make a clustering and then want to write the single clusters back to excel.
If you want to do it manually you can use the "Filter Examples" Operator and filter for the specific cluster.
You can also do it automatically with the "Loop Values" Operator, where you set the loop attribute to cluster and use the iteration macro inside the loop to filter your data. Then you could store your data and use the iteration macro also for the file name.
See the sample process below (you can copy it and paste it in the XML panel directly in RapidMiner):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="7.0.0">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="7.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_data" compatibility="7.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="68" name="Generate Data" width="90" x="112" y="34"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_id" compatibility="7.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="82" name="Generate ID" width="90" x="246" y="34"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="k_means" compatibility="7.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="82" name="Clustering" width="90" x="447" y="34">
        <parameter key="k" value="5"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="loop_values" compatibility="7.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="82" name="Loop Values" width="90" x="715" y="34">
        <parameter key="attribute" value="cluster"/>
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" breakpoints="after" class="filter_examples" compatibility="7.1.000-SNAPSHOT" expanded="true" height="103" name="Filter Examples" width="90" x="179" y="34">
            <list key="filters_list">
              <parameter key="filters_entry_key" value="cluster.equals.%{loop_value}"/>
            </list>
          </operator>
          <connect from_port="example set" to_op="Filter Examples" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Filter Examples" from_port="example set output" to_port="out 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_example set" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_out 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_out 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Generate Data" from_port="output" to_op="Generate ID" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Generate ID" from_port="example set output" to_op="Clustering" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Clustering" from_port="clustered set" to_op="Loop Values" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Loop Values" from_port="out 1" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot David. Yes I understood your solution a bit. I will google it further. Are there any ready-made tutorials for this. And can I write all my clusters to different sheets in excel as well? Appreciate your help.